# Одним запросом в бд заполнить 3 seleсt

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно одним запросом в базу заполнить 3 селектора, в коде представлен первый селект где `rparent = 0`. Нужно выводить ещё два селекта, где `rparent = 1` и `rparent = 2`

```
$selector = "SELECT * FROM rubrics WHERE rparent = 0";
$result_selector = mysql_query($selector);


 echo "<select name = ''>";

while($object = mysql_fetch_object($result_selector)){

echo "<option value = '$object->rid' > $object->rname_ru </option>";

}

echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Только надо пользоваться не убогими устаревшими функциями mysql_fetch, а прекрасной новой библиотекой PDO

```
$sql = "select rparent, rid, rname_ru FROM rubrics WHERE rparent IN(1,2,3)";
$selects = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

и дальше просто перебираешь в цикле элементы массива `$selects`:

```
foreach($selects[0] as $obj )
{
    echo "<option value = '$obj->rid' > $obj->rname_ru </option>";
}
```

И потом точно так же для 1 и 2